# Run hook update N in different batches

Tags: hooks, updating

I am trying to update drupal. I want to break the updates into 2 different runs/groups. I want run the second batch of updates after the first is done.
The first batch contains the updates from the drupal update and the second should contain the custom ones.
Is this possible in any way?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do this by Drush.
Install drush

```
1. drush up drupal  ->> it will update only core drupal
2. drush pm-update --no-core <modulename>   ->> it will update only mentioned module.
```